# To send the below specific json on kafka topic

Tags: java, json, apache-kafka

**JSON**

```
{
    "data": {
        "userName": "abc",
        "message": "Testing service",



            "mobileno": [{
                    "mobilenumber": "90000000000"
                },

                {
                    "mobilenumber": ""
                },

                {
                    "mobilenumber": ""
                },

                {
                    "mobilenumber": ""
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

We have to send the above json on kafka topic but we are not able to send the specific json format it .

Below is the code that we are trying:

**MobileController class**

```
           @Controller
    public class MobileController {

        @RequestMapping(value = "/mobile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public void dataFromEs(@RequestParam("name") String name,
                @RequestParam("message") String message,
                @RequestParam("mobileNo") String[] mobileNo)
                throws JsonProcessingException {
            Properties props = new Properties();

            props.put("metadata.broker.list", "hostname:port");
            props.put("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder");
            props.put("request.required.acks", "1");

            ProducerConfig producerConfig = new ProducerConfig(props);

            List<KeyedMessage<String, String>> msgList = new ArrayList<KeyedMessage<String, String>>();

            String topic = "qwerty";// topic name
            Data data = new Data();
            data.setUserName(name);
            data.setMobileNo(mobileNo);
            data.setMessage(message);
                              KeyedMessage<String, String> keyedMessage1 = new KeyedMessage<String, String>(
                    topic, data.toString());

            msgList.add(keyedMessage1);

            Producer<String, String> post = new Producer<String, String>(
                    producerConfig);

            // post.send(messages);

            post.send(msgList);

        }
    }
```

**Data class**

Below is the getter setter class

```
    import java.util.Arrays;

    public class Data {
    private String userName;
    private String message;
    private String[] mobileNo;
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
    public String[] getMobileNo() {
        return mobileNo;
    }
    public void setMobileNo(String[] mobileNo) {
        this.mobileNo = mobileNo;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{data: {userName:" + userName + ", message:" + message
                + ", mobileNo:mobilenumber" + Arrays.toString(mobileNo) + "}";
    }

    }
```

We are making one webservice and in controller we will have the user name ,message and multiple mobile numbers.
i.e one user will send message to multiple mobile numbers. Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: so, what? are you getting an error or something?

Comment: getting data in this format:data {userName:mohan, message:hi, mobileNo:[9999999, 99999, 99999, 999999, 88888, 77777]}

Comment: so, what? are you getting an error or something?

Comment: the above output we are getting but not the expected one

Comment: "data":{"mobileno":{"mobilenumber":["11111111111111111"],"mobilenumber2":"0000456","mobilenumber3":"7773456"},"userName":"vishal","message":"qwerty"}}

Comment: we are even now able to get the output but the problem that we are facing right now is different key and different values but what we want is same key and different value

Comment: JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject obj2 = new JSONObject();
obj2.put("mobilenumber", mobileNo);
          obj2.put("mobilenumber2", "0000456");
          obj.put("mobileno",obj2 );
         obj.put("userName", name);
          obj.put("message",message);
          JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
          ja.put(obj);
          JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject();
          mainObj.put("data", obj);

Comment: And what is the difference? Apart from formatting they seem to represent the same structure

Comment: this is what we have done

Comment: how I can get same key with different values like: 
            "mobileno": [{
                    "mobilenumber": "90000000000"
                },

                {
                    "mobilenumber": ""
                },

                {
                    "mobilenumber": ""
                },

                {
                    "mobilenumber": ""
                }
            ] Iam getting the output as:
 
"data":{"mobileno":{"mobilenumber":["11111111111111111"],"mobilenumber2":"000045‌​6","mobilenumber3":"7773456"},